# Swagger available to the world wide web

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, rest-api, swagger

On any given Magento2 website, you can navigate to https://yourmagentostore.com/swagger and access the swagger UI for API methods.

One of the methods that you can test before being authenticated is getting a token. You get that by using the `integrationAdminTokenService`.
All that method needs is the admin username and password.

To me this seems like a security risk. Any bot can brute Force this form to try and guess the admin credentials.
So even if you created a complicated path to your admin route, here's an easy place for someone else to try and guess it.

Am I missing something? Are you supposed to disable swagger for your production environment?

While I'm at it, I guess you don't need the swagger UI, anyone can just brute Force the API `integrationAdminTokenService` to try and get the user credentials.

Does Magento2 have any measures in place to prevent such attacks?

Answer (score 2):

According to Magento Dev docs,
By default, the /swagger endpoint is open on Magento instances. Leaving it open on a public instance could potentially expose system information that should not be readable.

To close off the /swagger endpoint, disable the following modules:

- Swagger
- SwaggerWebapi
- SwaggerWebapiAsync

Reference : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/generate-local.html?itm_source=devdocs&itm_medium=search_page&itm_campaign=federated_search&itm_term=swagger

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by disabling the Magento Swagger module:

```
bin/magento module:disable Magento_Swagger
```

Hope it works.